# Do PHP's logical operators work as JavaScript's?

Tags: php, logical-operators, operator-precedence

One of the things I like the most of JavaScript is that the logical operators are very powerful:

- `&&` can be used to safely extract the value of an object's field, and will return null if either the object or the field has not been initialized

  ```
  // returns null if param, param.object or param.object.field
  // have not been set
  field = param && param.object && param.object.field;
  ```
- `||` can be used to set default values:

  ```
  // set param to its default value
  param = param || defaultValue;
  ```

Does PHP allow this use of the logical operators as well?

Comment: No, they act as boolean expression operators, you'll get back true or false.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHP returns `true` or`false`. But you can emulate JavaScript's `r = a || b || c` with:

```
$r = $a ?: $b ?: $c;
```

Regarding 'ands', something like:

```
$r = ($a && $a->foo) ? $a->foo->bar : null;
```

Comment: I was about to post the same thing. Note that this feature exists of PHP 5.3.

Comment: Wow. It's nice to see PHP supports GCC's `?:` idiom. And I'm using PHP 5.3.5.

Comment: PHP's ?: works like JavaScript's ||. But perhaps there is no equivalent for && in PHP.

Answer (score 9):

PHP logical operators do not return the value on any of their sides : they will always get you a boolean.

For instance, doing :

```
$result = $a && $b;
```

Will always make `$result` contain a boolean : `true` or `false` -- and never `$a` nor `$b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up similar functionality using [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Answer (score 1):

**Revised**:

With respect to logical ANDing in PHP to achieve the same kind of result as JavaScript, you could use a variant of the traditional ternary, as follows:

```
<?php
    // prelim
    $object = new stdClass;
    $object->field = 10;
    $param = new stdClass;
    $param->object = $object;

    // ternary variant     
    $field = !($param && $param->object)?:  $param->object->field;
    echo $field,"\n";

    // alternative to ANDing
    $field = get_object_vars( $param->object )["field"] ?? null;
    echo $field,"\n";
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/OZF61)

The "Elvis" operator "?:" only assigns the result to $field if the conditional expression is false.  So, if $param exists as well as $param->object, then you have to use the NOT operator ("!") in order to get the desired result.

You may also accomplish the objective of getting the field data without ANDing  by utilizing  the null coalescing operator ("??") in PHP 7 in tandem with `get_object_vars()`.